# Hiding Pivot Chart Filters in Excel

Tags: excel, pivot-chart, vba

I have a data table that will split into 20 types of Pivot charts.  I was hoping to use a filter, so that I could just use the same set of data.
I've done it, but each pivot chart has the same repeated filter items on the top.

Is it possible to hide the filters in a Pivot Chart either by VBA or using options that I'm not finding?

Comment: tell you a cool trick... try recording a macro. :)

Comment: Yes, it's my favorite trick. :) I would if I knew how to hide them in the first place.

Comment: in that case always try clicking  and right clicking . Check for the new options that excel presents :) By the way see the answer.